# Ajax select and automatically load data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My form:

```
<form>
  <select id="f_name"><?php echo $fname ?></select>
  <select id="l_name></select>
</form>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#f_name").change(function(){
    var fname = $('this').val();
    $.ajax({
      type :'POST',
      data :{name:fname},
      url   :"fullname.php",
      success : function(data){
        $('#l_name').html(data);
      }     
    });
  });
});
```

My `fullname.php`:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $f_name = $_POST['name'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT last_name FROM fullname WHERE first_name = '$f_name'");
  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  echo $res;
}
```

The last name wont appear as I select first name.

Answer (score 1):

Formation of your form is not correct:

```
<form>
  <select id="f_name"><?php echo $fname ?></select>
  <select id="l_name></select>
</form>
```

It should be:

```
<form>
  <select id="f_name">
    <option><?php echo $fname ?></option>
  </select>
  <select id="l_name></select>
</form>
```

Your script should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#f_name").change(function(){
    var fname = $('this').val();
    $.ajax({
      type :'POST',
      data :{name:fname},
      url :"fullname.php",
      success : function(data){
        $('#l_name').html('<option>'+data+'</option>');
      }   
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you
does this work  "$('#l_name').html('<option>'+data+'</option>'); " if my tag is input?

Comment: i still got nothing :(

Comment: can u log data in success ? and tell us what it is

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#f_name").change(function(){
    var fname = $('this').val();
    $.ajax({
      type :'POST',
      data :{name:fname},
      url :"fullname.php",
      success : function(data){    
        for (i in data) {                        
          $("#l_name").html("<option>'+data[i]+'</option>");
        }
      }   
   });
  });
});
```